# ng build fails with "operation not permitted, mkdir "\dir" in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I searched a lot,but cannot find necessary answer for me.After I open my created Angular2&Spring Boot project in another computer I cannot build project again with ng build.Error says:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Vusala'
>       at Error (native)

C:\Users\Vusala is old directory.I don't know how update this to new directory where my project files is there(C:\My projects).

I use IntelliJ.
Please,if you experienced with this issue,help me

Comment: could you please post contents of your angular-cli.json

Comment: Thank you,@РоманГуйван.I understood.I sould change outDir in angular-cli.json.Yes?

Comment: Guess you may try first and see how it goes, right?

Comment: Yes,it worked!Thanks

Comment: you need to close the question as resolved then

Comment: Thanks,i added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just I should change outDir in angular-cli.json file.Because when I write this project I changed it for seeing index.html in spring boot.
Thanks for hint @Роман Гуйван